# Gridview is not filling the entire Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I need a small help for designing a layout like Instagram.
My Gridview is not taking the entire screen, hence the main page is not scrollable. NEED HELP

**Structure**

[image]

**Screen**

[image]

Comment: Check the height and width of GridView's parent view.

Comment: try to use recycler view using grid layout manager and keep height as wrap content.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`: make `NestedScrollView`'s height be `match_parent`, and a `LinearLayout`'s height that is inside that nested scroll view - `wrap_content`.

`NestedScrollView` supports scrollable views in it without any problems.

And height of your `GridView` should be `wrap_content` too.

You will need to update your app/gradle file with this:

`com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0`

Replace 26.1.0 on version that you use if needed.